# Java: Pass a class that extends X and implements X

Tags: java, class, arguments, extends, implements

I can do this:

```
private void doSomething(Class<? extends OtherClass> clazz) {
    doSomethingEpicWithClass(clazz);
}
```

But I can't do this:

```
private void doSomethingAsWell(Class<? extends OtherClass implements OtherInterface> clazz) {
    doSomethingEpicWithClass(clazz);
    doSomethingEpicWithInterface(clazz);
}
```

Makes sense to you? Great. So how would I check if a passed class extends something and implements something? There isn't even an "implement" keyword for this case.

Comment: There is no `<? implements Interface>` in java, only `<? extends Interface>`

You can do `private <T extends OtherClass & OtherInterface> void doSomethingAsWell(Class<T> clazz)`

Comment: Yep, it works. I just placed the thing in the wrong place. Thx